# Aspose.Cells for .NET Enable Data Filtering

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose-cells

I just started working with the `Aspose.Cell`'s library for .NET and am having some issues finding documentation on how to enable Data Filtering for an output Excel sheet.

I understand this functionality is built into `Aspose.Cells.GridWeb` and documented here (http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Data+Filtering) however I cannot use this namespace to produce a document with this filtering enabled.

Is this functionality just not possible through the use of `Aspose`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aspose provides this functionality through the Aspose.Cells.AutoFilter object.

The documentation can be found here: 
https://apireference.aspose.com/net/cells/aspose.cells/autofilter

And some examples can be found here:
https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Data+Filtering

To add autofilter to a heading row:

```
//Creating AutoFilter by giving the cells range of the heading row
worksheet.AutoFilter.Range = "A1:B1";
```

Comment: Both are dead links.

Answer (score 0):

I set `AutoFilter` on the first row this way:

```
var idxLastColumn = worksheet.Cells.MaxDataColumn;
var firstRowLastCellName = CellsHelper.CellIndexToName(1, idxLastColumn);
worksheet.AutoFilter.Range = $"A1:{firstRowLastCellName}";
```

See https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/data-filtering/#autofilter-with-asposecells